# Do you use a comma before "rather than"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

For example:

> "The author of this story tries to express the feeling of the hunted, rather than the hunter"

Should the comma go  before "*rather than*" or not?

Another example:

> "Game refers to the sport of hunting in general, rather than the just the competition"

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Proofreading requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr. Yes.

Bear in mind that punctuation is a matter of *style*, **not grammar**, and as such you should be guided by your manual of style, either the one you've adopted or the one thrust upon you. I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which advises that "**antithetical" phrases** should be separated from the word they *modify* by a comma. You can see this rule in operation above: I've separated the phrase "not grammar" from the word "style", the former standing in contrast to the latter. In your example, you've contrasted "the hunted" with its opposite the "hunter" using *rather*, so if you choose to follow *CMS*, you'll use the comma.